# What is the best way to check out all the release notes for TCL 8.x

Tags: tcl

I see 8.5 release note, http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/tcl8.5#Release_Notes, but googling around does not return other versions easily.

I am mostly interested in the features introduced in each 8.x release. Is there some central place I can check out? Or what is the best way to do that?

I just downloaded 8.6.1 source, I only see Changelog file which pretty much is a long list of bug fixes, it is not clear what/whether new feature introduced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The summary of the ChangeLog/commit history is in the `changes` file in each Tcl source distribution. The one from Tcl 8.6.1 can be downloaded from [here](http://core.tcl.tk/tcl/raw/changes?name=ee9581961cbc6c9a330284cdc79b6c3a80542363) (way too long to include!) and the parts that you are interested in are toward the bottom. (It goes back to about Tcl 3.0, so there's a lot of history in there.)

Summaries of recent releases are on the [Tcler's Wiki](http://wiki.tcl.tk/405).

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a summary of changes in 8.6.1 yet… :-(